# Javascript Regex to get specific string from two differently-formatted text blocks

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a single regex that I can use in Javascript that would allow me to extract **just the tracking number** from two different formats of plain text order confirmation emails:

First confirmation email:

*(the tracking number is always the line right below "Tracking Number")*

```
Tracking Number
1ZA828Y12313205351
```

Second confirmation email:

*(the tracking number is always on the same line, after the colon and a (possibly) variable number of space characters)*

```
Carrier Tracking Number :  582612345988
```

Also, just to clarify: The tracking numbers will always be any combination of capital letters and numbers (and will not necessarily start with "1Z").

Comment: `Tracking Number\s*:?\s*([A-Z0-9]+)`, then print the group index 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:Carrier )?Tracking Number\s*:?\s*([A-Z0-9]+)
```

Try this.Just grab the capture or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/28

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon. This seems to work for PHP, but I changed it to Javascript in the sidebar and it's correctly displaying the matches, but not actually capturing the capturing group. [link](https://regex101.com/r/uD3hP9/1). In my Javascript I'm doing this: `var trackingNum = messageText.match(/(?:Carrier )?Tracking Number\s*:?\s*([A-Z0-9]+)/gm);` and it's returning the whole "group #0" (which includes the "Tracking Number" or "Carrier Tracking Number" text.

Comment: @mike you need to use `group 1`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got it working by referencing group 1 like this: `var trackingNumRegex = /(?:Carrier )?Tracking Number\s*:?\s*([A-Z0-9]+)/gm;
            var trackingNum = trackingNumRegex.exec(messageText)[1];`

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple

```
[A-Z0-9]([A-Z0-9])+
```

It may sound ugly, but if you know that there are never two upper-case characters one after another, it will work.

Comment: This captures the entire tracking number but only matches the last character. [link](https://regex101.com/r/eU9sL9/2)

Comment: @mike, no, according to what you've sent, it matches the whole number, just taht it separates it into two groups.

Comment: This worked for what I needed: `([A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9])+` [link](https://regex101.com/r/eU9sL9/3)

Comment: @mike I guess the problem was related to the grouping. Anyway, I was close :)

Comment: Spoke too soon here too - that worked when testing only on that sample text, but went crazy when unleashed in the context of the entire message body.

Comment: @mike ... and it makes sense, as it doesn't depend on context - just on the combination of characters and numbers.